# JNLP can't find main class built with Maven

Tags: java, maven, jar, jnlp

I'm trying to convert an applet to a regular java application, using JNLP to run with. **When running directly it works. But if I run via JNLP I get the stack trace below.**

```
at com.sun.javaws.LaunchDownload.getMainClassName(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.doLaunchApp(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

**Main Java Class (App.java)**

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String porta = args[0];
    String dados = args[1];
    String etiquetaBytes = args[2];
    DadosEtiqueta[] dadosEtiqueta = getJsonFormString(dados, DadosEtiqueta[].class);
    ...
}
```

**JNLP file (config.jnlp)**
This is where the jar execution is configured

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jnlp spec="1.0+" codebase="http://172.16.3.5:8080/vendor" href="jnlp/config.jnlp">
    <information>
        <title>App Title</title>
        <vendor>Vendor Name</vendor>
        <offline-allowed/>
    </information>
    <resources>
        <j2se version="1.7+"/>
        <jar href="dir1/dir2/dir3/app-title.jar" main="true" />
    </resources>
    <application-desc/>
</jnlp>
```

**Maven Jar Plugin (pom.xml)**
This plugin is setting the main class.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <archive>
            <manifest>
                <mainClass>myPackage.App</mainClass>
            </manifest>
        </archive>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: After compiling, in the `<project>/target` folder, What is the content of the resulting manifest file ?

Comment: Manifest-Version: 1.0
Archiver-Version: Plexus Archiver
Built-By: franco.pan
Created-By: Apache Maven 3.3.9
Build-Jdk: 1.8.0_144
Main-Class: myPackage.App

Comment: What is the Exception (not only the first lines of the stacktrace) you got  ? -- Is the jar located in `http://172.16.3.5:8080/vendor/dir1/dir2/dir3/app-title.jar` ?

Comment: Are you using some *Web Start* / *JNLP* maven plugin such as [Mojo webstart](http://www.mojohaus.org/webstart/webstart-maven-plugin) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your JNLP is not valid.

(see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/deploymentInDepth/jnlpFileSyntax.html):

> Note: A JNLP file must contain one of the following: application-desc, applet-desc, component-desc, or installer-desc.

And `main-class` should be required for `application-desc`.

Try to add

```
<application-desc main-class="myPackage.App" />
```

There might be a need to add `name`, `width`, `height` too but the description is not very accurate on that.

Comment: *"There might be a need to add `name`, `width`, `height` too but the description is not very accurate on that."* Those are only relevant to `applet-desc` (for applets). OP: Be sure to check the JNLP using JaNeLA, available at my [share drive](https://drive.google.com/drive/#folders/0B5B9wDXIGw9lUnJaUjA2cmlVRE0).

Comment: l read that too. But the example states these parameters for application-desc too where the spec does not.

Comment: I have a considerable experience with applets, and for them, the three params make sense. E.G. width and height are (or at least were) more common for applets because their size was set by the HTML in which they were embedded. OTOH for a desktop app. the size is set by either `pack()` (minimum size needed for the components in the GUI) or `setSize(..)`. The `name` param is also for applets, in that it was a way to identify one of several applets in an applet context (applets that might be embedded in the same web page). It allowed for inter-applet communication, among other things.